# On back button fragment not shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 activities. Second activity has a fragment. When I click back from 3rd activity, 2nd activity is not shown.Instead goes to 1st activity. While debugging, it is going to oncreateview method of fragment on backpress from 3rd activity & view is also returned but not visible on screen. It seems it comes on the screen for fraction of second and goes to first activity, hence not visible.

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: Do you maybe have `finish()` in your 2nd activity on starting the 3rd? And do share relevant code.